# Steps to renovate uneven oak tiled Parquetry on cement?

Tags: floor, parquet, kitchen-island

I have Romanoff oak parquetry on the floors, new one shown [here](https://www.romanoff.fi/verkkokauppa/puulattia/massiiviparketti/roma-tammi-natur-mosaiikki-160mm/) with 160mm tiles. The floor is uneven. The old parquetry in the pictures has become a bit dark that I want to polish besides filling the hole with new parquetry tiles. The photos below show the hole, filling the earlier kitchen island, which I now want to have as open space.

[image]

[image]

[image]

where you can see that current parquetry is perfectly aligned as shown by laser, also in vertical way.

The size of the area is 2m2, taking 80 new tiles (4 x 20), surrounded by already installed parquetry. The exact size for the backer board is 0.64m x 3.2m (=4*0.16 x 20*0.16) i.e. 2.048m2 -- BUT the problem is that the middle-layer cement is not even, it is 1cm in other end while 2cm in other end. Only backer board available is even quality of 2cm thickness which would require grinding about 1cm concrete.

I have identified the following steps:

I. straighten up the underlying concrete with a spirit level and sanding/grinding? How coarse does the underlying floor stay for the glue to attach to it later?

II. installation of some other type of floor between the cement and the parquetry

II.1. install noise-cancellation floor if needed

II.2. the floor has 1cm cement on the other end, 2cm cement at the other end and everything in-between between 1cm and 2cm -- so floor is not nicely levelled horizontally.

III. using 2-phase glue to install parquetry to the extra layer

IV. sand the installed floor and the old floor to make it on the same level

where the hardest part is probably II because we cannot use ready-made concreate layers, the backer board get thinner on the other end and the market seems to have only 2cm backer boards available.

**How to renovate the old parquetry with a hole in the old parquetry?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to make the floor even first like with ready concrete.**

Then, you can follow the tips outlined by the firm:

2. if there is any space left after the concrete, you can use a particle board like 4 T030 9 mm (you should not need this if the concrete well done)
3. Damtec standard 3mm with noise cancelling

For polishing the parquetry after its gluing and installation

1. underlying surface thing (pohjalakka in Finnish) is surfaced with Flotex -tool
2. middle scrubbing and upper surface thing (välihionta, pintalakka in Finnish) is surfaced with Mohair thing (lasta in FInnish) about 2-3 times

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better ways of doing this but I could see either laying down backer board of the thickness needed to make the parquetry the same height as the existing. You'll want to lay the backer board in a bed of thinset and a few concrete screws. Or depending on the size of area you may be able to get away with pouring self-leveling concrete <s>mortar</s> to the desire thickness and then the parquetry. The existing concrete will need some prep to get it to adhere well.

Comment: 1) The concrete is not even so how would you straighten, level the floor before adding the backer board? 2) By grinding the floor first and how coarse would you leave the underlying concrete for the backer board for the glue/screws to attach? The size is 2m2 where I need to install 80 pieces (4 x 20) of 0.16m x 0.16m new tiles.

Comment: The self-leveling concrete may be the option you want to consider. It will level out the floor. I don't know how thick you can make it, so I don't know if you can just use it purely to level to the needed thickness for the parquetry.

Comment: It sounds like Self-leveling concrete is the only option here because the floor has 2cm middle-layer concrete in other end and 1cm middle-layer concrete in the opposite end -- so we cannot use equally-sized 2cm backer board. What kind of self-leveling concrete would you suggest?

Comment: I don't have any particular type I can recommend. Someone else may chime in with one. I've always just used what I found in the hardware stores that from what the description says to meet my needs.